# Make changes in the product page without changing core files

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, product-page

I have a .html file which is essentially a little gallery program that takes a series of pictures of a product and combines them to let the user rotate the product 360 degrees.

I am looking to make some sort of extension that would allow me to inject the .html file in the product page. (Possibly some example code which would allow me to create my own extension)

Or maybe if anyone knows any other way of doing this without modifying the core files on magento.

P.S.
I am using magento 1.9.2.4

Comment: I think you need to override view.phtml file

Answer (score 0):

This is only for explaining

you need change block type core/template to tag/popular

getLayout()->createBlock('tag/popular')->setTemplate('tag/popular.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

OR

give a name of block

```
{{block type="core/template" template="theme/home_banner.phtml"  name="myname"}}
```

then

by using xml reference include tags/popular.phtml

create local.xml at app/design/frontend/youupackage/yourtemplate/layout

put this code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<cms_index_index translate="label">
  <reference name="myname">
        <block type="tag/popular" name="home_tags_popular" template="tag/popular.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

and put below code at home_banner.phtml

```
echo $this->getChildHtml('home_tags_popular');
```

I think overriding would to better then modifing the core file

Create your own module and than override the block.Here are some links to guide you on how to do it: http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-part10-series-overriding, http://magentocustom.blogspot.com/2011/05/how-to-override-magento-block-classes.html, http://prattski.com/2010/06/24/magento-overriding-core-files-blocks-models-resources-controllers/